# Clipboard com filtro de conteúdo - Autohotkey

Tags: script, autohotkey

vocês tem ideia de como automatizar a seguinte situação?

Estou usando o Autohotkey para isso.

Vou dizer a situação e em seguida direi as hipóteses que considerei (parte delas só, já que não consegui terminar)

1 - Dou ctrl+c num conteúdo com várias linhas, vou chamá-las de 1,2,3,4,5 e 6 para facilitar a lógica.

Quero apenas copiar a linha 2, 3, 4 e 5 mas também com seleção de conteúdo nas linhas, ou seja, não copiar a linha 2 toda, apenas os números (excluir os textos). O mesmo vale pras outras linhas, porém com outro tipo de filtro.

2 - O script manda então pro clipboard somente o conteúdo desejado da linha 2, 3, 4 e 5 e então insere num arquivo de saída somente o conteúdo desejado da linha 2 com outro texto padrão. O mesmo acontece para as outras linhas.

Exemplo: A linha 2 possui "XYZ123". O script copia "123" apenas e manda pro arquivo de saída "ABC123". O mesmo ocorre pras outras linhas.

3 - O script após copiar todas as linhas, insere uma nova linha 7 de minha escolha que existirá apenas no arquivo de saída.

4 - O script então espera o próximo CTRL+C para repetir o processo com o próximo CTRL+C.

PS: As linhas nem sempre estão na mesma ordem. Por exemplo, o conteúdo da linha 2 as vezes está na linha 3. Porém sempre existe uma palavra-chave em cada linha que possa ser usada pra filtrar o seu conteúdo.

O próximo passo seria dar ctrl+c já automaticamente no conteúdo, mas vou me ater primeiro a resolver esse impasse.

Hipóteses que considerei:

1 - Para separar cada linha e colar sempre na mesma ordem, usaria variáveis para assumir o valor da linha já com o conteúdo indesejado excluído.

2 - Caso não consiga automatizar a ordem das linhas, não tem problema usar hotkeys para decidir qual linha é qual ou uma mensagem do sistema me perguntar isso e agir conforme a resposta.

```
clipboard =  ; Começa o script com o clipboard vazio

ClipWait  ; Espera encher o clipboard
FileAppend, %clipboard%`r`n, C:\Users\caio_\Desktop\Teste de programação\Saída.txt ; Joga pro arquivo de saída
MsgBox Control-C copied the following contents to the clipboard:`n`n%clipboard% ; Aparece uma confirmação do que foi copiado (vou tirar quando estiver tudo funcionando)

Reload ; Pra reabrir o script
Sleep 1000 ; 
MsgBox, 4,, The script could not be reloaded. Would you like to open it for editing?
IfMsgBox, Yes, Edit
return
```

***Edit para explicar melhor a dúvida: o problema é que eu não consegui achar um jeito de filtrar o conteúdo do clipboard e por isso não consegui integrar outros comandos pra resultar na minha ideia. O objetivo é achar um jeito de filtrar o conteúdo, isso que eu realmente não consegui achar. Fazendo isso, consigo descobrir como trabalhar o resto. Descrevi a situação toda caso alguém dê uma ideia boa de como jogar isso pra um arquivo de saída da melhor forma.***

Comment: A idéia está até que bem descrita, mas qual é a dúvida exatamente? Se puder [edit] a postagem e comenter o que tentou, e qual o problema encontrado, ou o que não deu certo, talvez fique mais fácil ajudar. Da forma como está, ficou um bocado ampla e vaga a pergunta. Talvez isso ajude: [Tour], [Ask] e [Help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar deste tópico ter mais de um ano, pode ser que a solução ajude outras pessoas.

O desejado aqui é uma pesquisa e substituição regex; [RegExMatch](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm) é a função para este trabalho.

O ahk utiliza [este tipo de regex](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm)

Exemplo:

```
Loop {
  Clipboard := ""
  ClipWait
  clip_conteudo := Clipboard

  ; Separa o conteúdo do clipboard em linhas. clip_conteudo passa a ser Array.
  clip_conteudo := StrSplit(clip_conteudo, "`n")

  ; Agora basta tratar o conteúdo de cada linha Pode facilmente se converter em um for
  RegExMatch(clip_conteudo[1], "([^ ]*\d+[^ ]*)", linha_1)
  RegExMatch(clip_conteudo[2], "([^ ]*\d+[^ ]*)", linha_2)
  RegExMatch(clip_conteudo[3], "([^ ]*\d+[^ ]*)", linha_3)
  RegExMatch(clip_conteudo[4], "([^ ]*\d+[^ ]*)", linha_4)
  RegExMatch(clip_conteudo[5], "([^ ]*\d+[^ ]*)", linha_5)
  RegExMatch(clip_conteudo[6], "([^ ]*\d+[^ ]*)", linha_6)

  ; Trata-se dos dados de maneira desejada
  linha_1 := RegExReplace(linha_1, "(\D+)(\d+)", "ABC$2")
  linha_7 := linha_2 + linha_3

  ; Mesma coisa que: clip_conteudo = %linha_1%`n%linha_2%`n [...]
  clip_conteudo =
  (LTrim
    %linha_1%
    %linha_2%
    %linha_3%
    %linha_4%
    %linha_5%
    %linha_6%
    %linha_7%
  )

  FileAppend, %clip_conteudo%`n, Saída.txt 
}

Esc::ExitApp
```

Para o pseudo-texto:

```
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. XYZ123 .
It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC,
making it over 2000 years old.
Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and
1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum"
Generated 1 paragraph, 44 words, - bytes of Lorem Ipsum 27/03/2019
```

A pseudo-saída será:

```
ABC123
45
2000
1.10.32
1.10.33
1
2045
```